# Neural Network 0 vs -1

Tags: math, neural-network

I have seen a few times people using `-1` as opposed to `0` when working with neural networks for the input data. How is this better and does it effect any of the mathematics to implement it?

**Edit:** Using feedforward and back prop

**Edit 2:** I gave it a go but the network stopped learning so I assume the maths would have to change somewhere?

**Edit 3:** Finally found the answer. The mathematics for binary is different to bipolar. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recently found that the sigmoid and sigmoid derivative formula needs to change if using bipolar over binary.

Bipolar Sigmoid Function: `f(x) = -1 + 2 / (1 + e^-x)`

Bipolar Sigmoid Derivative: `f’(x) = 0.5 * (1 + f(x)) * (1 – f(x) )`

Comment: Look at this link for reference: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/c4a0095a-0465-4931-63e7-4c0cdbe2eacc.htm

Comment: thanks was tring to fin why my net wouldnt train with bipolar targets, realise signoid was not bipolar but couldnt find the derivative, working great now.

Comment: For completion: To extend from normal `f(x)=sigmoid` to `[a,b] sigmoid` (`[-1,+1]` in our case), take `g(x) = (b-a)f(x) + a` (becomes `2f(x) - 1` in our case)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a *long* time, but as I recall, it has no effect on the mathematics needed to implement the network (assuming you're not working with a network type that for some reason limits any part of the process to non-negative values).  One of the advantages is that it makes a larger distinction between inputs, and helps amplify the learning signal.  Similarly for outputs.

Someone who's done this more recently probably has more to say (like about whether the 0-crossing makes a difference; I think it does).  And in reality some of this depends on exactly what type of neural network you're using. I'm assuming you're talking about backprop or a variant thereof.

Comment: Yep using backprop. I can understand that the weighted input would be different (ie if the weight was 1.84, input of 0 would result in 0 and -1 would result in -1.84) but I don't know if it's better or not or why.

Comment: It does have an effect on the mathematics.

Answer (score -1):

The network learns quickly using -1/1 inputs compared to 0/1. Also, if you use -1/1 inputs, 0 means "unknown entry/noise/does not matter". I would use -1/1 as input of my neural network.

Comment: But do I have to change anything or should it work by just replacing 0 with -1. As I said, I gave it a go but I got weird results. The MSE kept outputting the same number through each epoch.